# Ajax begin form update the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my project, I have a main page for the document creation in `DocumentsController` where the user is able to change the status of the document. If the status is `NEW`, the user is allowed to add a new device ("part") to the document.

My goal is to insert a string to `div#newDevice` on ajax form submit. However, the html result is not rendered inside my main view but is rendered as a link `..../PartsBoxes/CreatePartial` instead.

How could I fix that issue?

My main page part:

```
<input type="button" value="Add a new box" id="addNewBoxButton" class="add_new_btn" />
<input type="button" value="Add box from db" id="addDBBoxButton" class="add_existent_btn" />

<hr />
<div id="newDevice"></div>
<hr />

 <script>
    $("#addNewBoxButton").on("click", function () {
        var deviceId = 1;
        $.get('@Url.Action("CreatePartial", "PartsBoxes")',{
            deviceId: deviceId
        },
            function (data) {
                $("#newDevice").html(data);
            });

    });
</script>
```

my partial view:

```
@model NTStock.Models.BoxPartsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreatePartial", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "newDevice" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DocumentId)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InternalName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InternalName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InternalName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        //......///

        <div class="form-group deviceManipulations">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeinstallationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeinstallationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeinstallationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save box" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and the method:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ContentResult CreatePartial(BoxPartsViewModel partsBox)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         //do something
      }
      return Content("string to return");
  }
```

as a result I get:
[image]

Comment: Can you post or highlight the HTML for your button and the #newBox? I cannot find it.

Comment: Try to change `return Content("string to return");` by `return Json(new { data = "string to return" });`. Also change the return type of the method `CreatePartial` to `JsonResult `

Comment: same result except the string i get `{"data":"string to return"}`

Comment: Also you markt the action with [HttpPost] while you send a GET

Comment: I send get to get the partial view with the form, and then I send post with submitting forms data

Comment: @GeekyNuns Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should be sure `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` is loaded in your page and you dont use jquery 1.9 version because it doesnt support jquery live methods.

Reference : http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Then I would suggest to use jquery `.load()` function to load partial view into target element and use `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` to achieve your goal like following.

**// jquery**

```
<script>
    $("#addNewBoxButton").on("click", function () {
        var deviceId = 1;
        $("#newDevice").load('@Url.Action("CreatePartial", "PartsBoxes")' + "/" deviceId );  
    });
</script>
```

**//controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult CreatePartial(BoxPartsViewModel partsBox)
{ 
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //do something
   }
   return Json(new { data = "string to return" });
}
```

Comment: In your answer the script is supposed to call get method, to get the partial views markup with ajax form, but controller is for the post which is done actually after get method. So I have no problems with my get method, but with post return, data is returned not to the  `UpdateTargetId` as it should be, but in separate page. And yes, I have included jquery.unobtrusive-ajax script and it is rendered.